# prime sieve returning some strange numbers

Tags: python, primes, sieve

I'm trying to develop a prime sieve, and on paper my algorithm makes perfect sense on paper, but returns a very short selection of composite numbers among the primes JUST above the square root.

For example, with a limit (finding all the primes up to the limit) of 10,000 (which has a square root of 100), the composite numbers it has mixed in with it's primes are 115, 119, 121, and 125 (all very close to (and above!) 100).

Please let me know what's wrong with my code, and which parts need fixing / how to fix it.

CLARIFICATION: I'm worried about the composite (non-primes) it returns, where in my primality testing did i go wrong and how could i correct it?

Here's my sieve so far:

```
def primes(limit):
    # Just make an empty list where the primes go
    prime = []
    # This next for loop just adds all the numbers of the form 6n+/-1 to the list, as all primes are of this form
    for i in range(1,limit / 6 + 1):
        prime.append(6*i - 1)
        prime.append(6*i + 1)
    # If the limit is divisible by 6, the last number on the list is sometimes over the limit
    if limit % 6 == 0 and prime[-1] > limit:
        prime.remove(prime[-1])
    # This next line just finds the place of the 'square root' of the limit, which is as high as it has to check for factors
    squareroot = min(range(len(prime)), key=lambda i: abs(prime[i]-(limit**0.5))) + 1
    # Removing composites BELOW the square root
    for p in prime[:squareroot][:]:
        for f in range(2, int(p ** 0.5) + 1):
            if p % f == 0:
                prime.remove(p)
                break
    # Removing composites ABOVE the square root
    for f in prime[:squareroot][:]:
        for p in prime[squareroot:]:
            if p % f == 0:
                prime.remove(p)
    return [2, 3] + prime
```

Comment: "the indentation is wonky in the first line only". It's quicker to select all the lines below that first line and click on the `{}` code button than to type that sentence.

Comment: I don't understand your actual problem: are you worried you get values above 100, or worried you get composite numbers?

Comment: All primes are not of the form `6n +/- 1`.

Comment: Peter wood -- yes they are, at least primes above 2 and 3. This has been mathematically proven. As for Evert, I'm worried i get composite numbers (like 115, 119, etc) - but all of the composites i get are right above the square root of the limit (in this case 10,000). I'm wondering why i'm getting these composites and how i can stop getting them.

Comment: But your list of primes doesn't include `2` and `3`.

Comment: What's the smallest `limit` it fails with?

Comment: Peter -- the list my function returns does in fact include 2 and 3 (look at the last line), the smallest limit it fails with is 901, as it returns 35 as a prime. I'd like to draw attention to the fact that the only errors it makes are found very very close above to the square root of the limit

Comment: I see. You don't need to consider `2` and `3` as factors because multiples of `6` have `2` and `3` as a factor, and `+/-1` won't.

Comment: `limit=1000` doesn't have `115` in the primes, but `limit=10000` does. `limit=8101` is when it appears..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason you are getting composites above the square root, is because of how your loops are built.  When an item is removed from a list, all the items at higher indexes shift down by one. So, when an item is removed in the first loop, the square root moves down.  When the second loop starts, `squareroot` isn't the index of the square root any more.

```
# Removing composites BELOW the square root
for p in prime[:squareroot][:]:
    for f in range(2, int(p ** 0.5) + 1):
        if p % f == 0:
            prime.remove(p)  # <- you removed an item from `prime`, so the
            break            # square root is now at prime[squareroot - 1]

# Removing composites ABOVE the square root
for f in prime[:squareroot][:]:    #    now p[squareroot] is actually a number
    for p in prime[squareroot:]:   # <- above the real square root, so this 
        if p % f == 0:             #    loop starts too high
            prime.remove(p)
```

One way to fix it would be to adjust the value of `squareroot` whenever a value is removed in the first loop.  Another would be to recalculate `squareroot` before the second loop.

It is generally a bad idea to add or remove items from a list while you are iterating over the list.  For example, items can be marked (e.g. setting them to zero or None) in one pass and then the unmarked items can be copied in a second pass.

**Edit** added example code to mark composites:

```
# Removing composites BELOW the square root
for i,p in enumerate(prime[:squareroot]):
    for f in range(2, int(p ** 0.5) + 1):
        if p % f == 0:
            prime[i] = 0  # <- mark composites
            break         

# Removing composites ABOVE the square root
for f in prime[:squareroot]:    
    if f == 0: 
        continue                              # skip composites
    for i,p in enumerate(prime[squareroot:]): # <- this loop is okay now
        if p % f == 0:            
            prime[i] = 0                      # mark composite

# at this point, prime contains 0's where the compsites were found
# and non-zeros for the primes.  Just need to collect all the
# non-zero elements.
result = []         
for p in prime:     
    if p:                    
        result.append(p)
```

There are other issues with your code, but that should answer your immediate question.  As you become more proficient with python, you will see further improvements you can make (A prime sieve can be written in about 6 lines of python).

Comment: Thank you -- I've heard that removing items while iterating can cause troubles, but is there really a way to avoid this?

Comment: added example code that doesn't remove items from `prime` while iterating over it.

Answer (score 3):

Once you remove primes below the square root, you can no longer use `squareroot` as an index into `primes`, since the length of `primes` will have changed.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it based off of T. Silver's response -- I just made it so that after making sure everything below the square root of the limit is prime, it finds the square root again. Here's the fixed code:

```
# Just make an empty list where the primes go
prime = []
# This next for loop just adds all the numbers of the form 6n+/-1 to the list, as all primes are of this form
for i in range(1,limit / 6 + 1):
    prime.append(6*i - 1)
    prime.append(6*i + 1)
# If the limit is divisible by 6, the last number on the list is sometimes over the limit
if limit % 6 == 0 and prime[-1] > limit:
    prime.remove(prime[-1])
# This next line just finds the place of the 'square root' of the limit, which is as high as it has to check for factors
squareroot = min(range(len(prime)), key=lambda i: abs(prime[i]-(limit**0.5))) + 1
# Removing composites BELOW the square root
for p in prime[:squareroot][:]:
    for f in range(2, int(p ** 0.5) + 1):
        if p % f == 0:
            prime.remove(p)
            break
# Here's where i put the fix!
squareroot = min(range(len(prime)), key=lambda i: abs(prime[i]-(limit**0.5))) + 1
# Removing composites ABOVE the square root
for f in prime[:squareroot][:]:
    for p in prime[squareroot:]:
        if p % f == 0:
            prime.remove(p)
return [2, 3] + prime
```